# Representing data as charts in Java

Tags: java, charts, report

I have three integer values. I need to represent these data as a chart. What should i do. Will iReports be the right option. If so give some pointers to tutorials for the IReports.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

iReports is too heavyweight for that. Use JFreeChart http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Comment: can i convert the report to pdf as in JasperReports

Comment: You'll have to use iText for PDF. If resulting document is relatively small there's no need to use iText. It is good for system that has several complex reports.